# How will Windows Account Change Affect TFS Accounts?

Tags: tfs

We are running TFS 2012. Our organization is currently creating new accounts for everyone as part of a migration.

What I know is that everyone will have two accounts listed in AD for a while:
OldDomain\DoeJ
NewDomain\DoeJ

This brings me to believe that SID will be different, among other things.

My question is, how would this affect our TFS environment? Will we lose any history associated with particular users? Will I have to go through each work item and reassign it to the new Windows account? Is there any way I can preserve this data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Identities Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#identities) which lists or changes the security identifier (SID) of users and groups in your deployment of TFS. You might need to change or update the SID for users and groups in one of the following scenarios:

- changing the domain of your deployment
- changing from a workgroup to a domain or from a domain to a workgroup
- **migrating accounts across domains in Active Directory**

Even though it's a powerful tool, but it has certain limitations. To help ensure a successful move, make sure that you understand the following requirements:

> - **Once a user account is present in TFS, it cannot be removed or have    another account mapped to it.** For example, if you are moving
>     DomainA/UserA to DomainB/UserB, the Identities command would only
>     work to migrate the user if `DomainB/UserB` is not already present in 
>     TFS.
> - Because the members of the local Administrators group are    automatically added to TFS, make sure to remove any accounts that you 
>     want migrated from that group before you change the domain or
>     environment.

Suggest you read up about this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-across-domains#move-tfs-user-and-service-accounts) as part of planning your move. You could also take a look at this blog  : [Migrating TFS Server or Collection to another domain](http://mohamedradwan.com/2014/04/05/migrating-tfs-server-or-collection-to-another-domain/). Be careful do not add the user such as `NewDomain\DoeJ` to TFS first, after upgrade SID, the history will keep without any problem.

---

Moreover, TFS use a background synchronization job, scheduled every hour, to look for changes in Active Directory (or the local machine workgroup if the server is not domain joined). You can force the job to run using any of [these techniques](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24305.how-to-synchronize-tfs-users-with-ad-active-directory.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the great info. I'll do some more research into it and come back with my results.

Comment: @getoutofmylaboratory Sure, any new question or info feel free to .update here.

Comment: It appears that tfsconfig is missing from the Tools directory. In fact, that directory is empty aside from a Templates folder with web.config inside it. C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Tools is the directory I checked. There is not a similar directory in Program Files (x86).

Comment: @getoutofmylaboratory Since you are using TFS 2012, TfsConfig is located in Drive:\%programfiles%\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Tools of your **application tier server**.   

If you cannot find the tool folder, you have to **make sure your TFS is configured properly**. Also run TFS best practice analyzer to check if there any configuration issues on your server machine. Please elaborate more details about your scenario if you have any specific settings.

Comment: Yes, I was looking in that path and the folder is empty. This was on the application tier. The database server and application tier are separate servers, though. Best Practices Analyzer shows critical items like: Cannot access Analysis Services. MSSQLServerOLAPService is not running. ReportingServices Web request call failed. Users <my account> does not have "Team Foundation Content Manager" permissions. And then a number of issues related to analysis db sync. Nothing mentioning that TFS files are missing.

Comment: I was able to use TfsConfig to update one account (which didn't have any history on it). Once we're ready to migrate the others  I will try it out and post back my results and mark as answer.

Comment: @getoutofmylaboratory Glad to here this. When you change identities, the target account or accounts must already exist in Windows.
You must **wait for the next identity synchronization** with Windows before the properties of accounts that you change with this command will be updated. This requirement includes changes from group to user, user to group, and domain account to local account.