# Default Project Team Missing After Migration

Tags: tfs, migration

We're in the middle of migrating our TFS instance from one environment to a new environment (not on same domain). Followed steps outlined as answer here:
[How will Windows Account Change Affect TFS Accounts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48672308/how-will-windows-account-change-affect-tfs-accounts)

Accounts have been successfully mapped to new accounts on that server. No issue there. One thing I'm noticing is that we can't get into any of our projects. When you click to view a project profile, it shows that no teams are available. When you click "New Team", it gives error: "Team is required. Session Id....". If you attempt to add a team with the name previously used in the old environment, it says it can't add the team because it already exists.

If you click "Configure features" on that same page, it walks you through the wizard which results in another error: "TF237090: Does not exist or access is denied."

For the record, we were using TFS 2012, detached and reattached project collections on a server with those versions. Upgraded there and then detached and reattached on our target server.

Any clue on how to add a pre-existing Team to a project or how to get around these errors? Everything else seems to be fine.

Comment: This is almost definitely an issue with permissions/domain moving. Team projects should immediately be accessible after an upgrade. I'd suggest redoing the migration and validating after each step. Migrate TFS 2012 to the new domain on a TFS 2012 instance. If it still works, continue. If it doesn't work, *fix it*. Don't just blindly move->upgrade in one shot without validating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment on Andy Li-MSFT's post, I ended up having to manually recreate teams and reassign permissions. The upgrade path from TFS 2012 - 2015/17 doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the Team and users are already there. 
So, just try to [remap the DBs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd?view=tfs-2015#remapdbs), then check it again.

If that still not work, I suggest redoing the migration as Daniel said.

You can also follow the steps mentioned in below article to do the migration:

[Move Team Foundation Server from one environment to another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ms404883(v=vs.120)#MoveAccounts)

Another similar thread for your reference : [TFS Group Identities are missing after TFS migration to a new domain - Members lost access to the project](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0b13bfc5-0ba9-4913-ad34-6d20b243af05/tfs-group-identities-are-missing-after-tfs-migration-to-a-new-domain-members-lost-access-to-the?forum=tfsintegration)

Comment: @getoutofmylaboratory Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: I ended up having to manually create the teams and reassigning permissions. The upgrade path from TFS 2012 to 2015/17 simply doesn't work.